# How to read data from mariadb using Spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, mariadb

I need to read a table from MariaDB by using Spark and Java.

I wrote a Java code for read table data from database.The connection is established successfully but it produces an error while reading the data. I am trying to read the table data as a dataframe. But the column name is shown as column value in result. find the code given below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

public class mariadb_to_csv {    
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String resourceName = "config.properties";
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        try(InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
            prop.load(resourceStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
            .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = spark.read().format("jdbc")
            .option("url","url_address")
            .option("driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
            .option("dbtable", "source_table")
            .option("user", "username")
            .option("password", "password")
            .load();
    jdbcDF.select(col("code"), col("name"), col("isActive"), col("createdByUser"), col("modifiedByUser")).show();       


     }
     }
```

In result, the column value is duplicated in column name.

[image: error image]

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Column "isActive" value is true, not the column name. Maybe, table contains such dummy data.

Answer (score 4):

Seems there is a problem with "maridb" connector.

Changing the host url

from `"jdbc:**mariadb**://${Hostname}:${Port}/${Database}"`

to `"jdbc:**mysql**://${Hostname}:${Port}/${Database}"`
solved the problem for me.

MariaDB and Databricks also used "jdbc" as connection url to explain how to read data from Mariadb using Spark.

1. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-columnstore-with-spark/#usage
2. https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html

Answer (score 0):

we fix the issue by creating a new spark sql dialect

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect

object MariaDBDialect extends JdbcDialect {
  override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String = colName

  override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:mariadb")
}
```

before reading your mariadb dataframe just call

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects
// register specific dialect for mariaDB as it isn't implemented in spark
JdbcDialects.registerDialect(MariaDBDialect)
```