# Spark custom schema & jdbc not rendering data properly

Tags: apache-spark

Code below prints the column names instead of the data.

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSQL-Analysis").setSparkHome("C:\\work\\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7").setMaster("local[*]");

    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(javaSparkContext.sc()).appName("SparkSQL").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc")
              .option("url", "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:4406/cra")
              .option("dbtable", "rpm_user")
              .option("user", "root")
              .option("password", "XXXXXX")
              .option("customSchema", "RU_CRD string, RU_CONTACT_NUMBER string, RU_UPD string")
              .load();

    jdbcDF.show();

    javaSparkContext.close();
```

What am i missing?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEydJ.png)

Comment: If there’s no data in the table then it would print only the header

Comment: @Salim - It is printing the rows check the above Output link but contains the column names instead of the data. This happens when give the customSchema in the option.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here [How to read data from mariadb using Spark java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718788/how-to-read-data-from-mariadb-using-spark-java)

Changing from 
jdbc:mariadb://localhost:4406/cra
to 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:4406/cra
fixed my problem.